# Allocate in C specific index range

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Is it possible to allocate specific index range in C , like they do in fortran :

```
allocate(f(istart-1:iend+1), u(istart-1:iend+1), uold(istart-1:iend+1))


do i = istart, iend
.
.
.
end do
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. In C it is quite senseless; all indexes start at 0.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie: You can always offset a pointer though. Admittedly not entire sanctioned by the standard gods, but in practice it tends to work.

Comment: @doynax can you give an example ?

Comment: You could use a function or a macro to do the index calculation for you in order to give yourself the illusion of addressing from `i` to `i+n` instead of from `0` to `n`.

Comment: This is a XY problem. There's no obvious reason why any program would ever need such a feature.

Comment: @Mp. Roe: Let me confess that I'm only guessing at the function of `allocate` in FORTRAN. The idea is something along these lines `char  zero_based[10], *const one_based = &zero_based[-1]`.

Comment: @Lundin: Presumably to reason is to ease the porting of FOTRAN code into C without introducing errors. Seems sensible enough to me, though ideally the code would be rewritten with the sensibilities of the target language in mind.

Comment: @Lundin It is very handy. You are just used to use a limited language. BTW it Fortran, not FORTRAN.

Comment: @doynax Then the next question is, why did the original program in FORTRAN need to utilize this useless language feature?

Comment: @VladimirF Because calculating an offset is rocket science, right? How can any programmer possibly master advanced math such as addition and subtraction? Clearly the language must handle that for them.

Comment: @Lundin Why do we even need high level languages? Who needs closures? Every programmer can write a function and a struct...

Comment: @VladimirF These languages all come from an era when everyone and their mother invented programming languages, though nobody quite knew what they were doing and therefore spat out countless of language features, just for the sake of having a language with a lot of features. C suffers a lot from this as well. (Variable-argument functions is a perfect example.) And as soon as a language supports a feature, no matter how useless, people will without doubt start to use that feature.

Comment: @Lundin Explain that to the authors of modern productive scientific languages like Chapel, Julia. Furthermore there is are so many flamewars whether arrays should start at 0 or 1. CS guys always swear at 0  and say others are stupid, but people doing practical computations will see that 1 is often better (and, actually sometimes -1 and sometimes -2). When I see the overwhelming amount of features coming in every revision of C++, than sorry, but this little feature is really nothing in comparison with THAT bloat.

Comment: @Lundin: Voter: "If elected, how do you propose the solve the issues in our society?", Candidate: "Well, I wouldn't start from here."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want basically boils down to setting the lower bound and upper bound of an array, as in Basic (and apparaently Fortran): `Dim Matrix(3, 4) As Integer`.

As a use I can think of processing a part in a sparse array without having to allocate the full array.

In C you can achieve this by using an integer variable that serves as an offset, as a trivial example:

```
int getElement(int *arr, int index, int offset)
{
    return *(arr + (index-offset));
}
```

Also more elaborate methods are possible, e.g.:

```
typedef struct MY_ARR {
    int *arr;
    int lowerbound;  // from
    int upperbound;  // up and including
} t_myArr;

t_myArr *newArr(int lower, int upper)
{
    t_myArr *p;
    if (!(p= malloc(sizeof(t_myArr))) return 0;
    if (!(p->arr= calloc(sizeof(int),upper-lower+1))) {free(p); return 0;}
    p->arr.lowerbound= lower;
    p->arr.upperbound= upper;
    return p;
}
int getElement(t_myArr *p, int element)
{
    if (!p || p->arr.lowerbound<element || element>p->arr.uperbound) return 0;
    return(*(p->arr+element-lowerbound));
}
```

In essence you have now created your own integer array type.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly, and it makes no sense in C because a array is a sequence of consecutive elements and the first element has index 0 *by definition*. And in fact the C standard says it explicitely:

> 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
>   
> ...
>   2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator []
>   is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th
>   element of E1 (counting from zero).

But you can easily simulate it by creating a new pointer with a specific offset. Assuming that you want an *array* accepting indexes for start (inclusive) to end (exclusive) (start and end being 2 integer values with end > start):

```
int * arr = malloc((end - start) * sizeof(int));
arr -= start; // must be done in two steps because malloc return a void*
              // and no pointer arithmetics is possible on void *;

for (int i=start; i<end; i++) {
    arr[i] = ...;
    ...
}
...
free(arr + start);  // do not forget the offset when freeing...
```

*By definition*, `arr[start] = *(arr + start) = *(arr_orig - start + start) = *arr_orig`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
int array[100];

#define Array(index) array[(index) - 10]

int main() {

  Array(10) = 1;  // actually the same as array[0];
  Array(11) = 2;  // actually the same as array[1];

  printf("%d\n", Array(10) + Array(11));

}
```

This is really a hack and I'd not advise using it actually.